# HTML (php, css, JS) - closing tag or inline comment being ignored

Tags: php, html, inline, comments

In this text

```
<div class="foo" <!-- onclick="bar();" --> /></div>
```

the `/>` is being shown within the browser (Chrome) and on iOS devices. My first guess was to delete the `/` from the `<div>` but then the `>` was still being shown within the browser, woe is me!

Solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

After discussing with the OP, it was found that the onclick method was still needed, so the solution was to use `<div class="foo" onclick="bar();"> </div>` without the 'commented code' in it.

**Original answer:**

Try -  `<div class="foo" <?php /* onclick="bar();" */ ?> > </div>` which will result in `<div class="foo"> </div>`. Notice that the entire thing is filtered by your PHP.

For JSP/ASP, use `<%-- --%>` style comments. `<div class="foo" <%-- onclick="bar();" --%> > </div>`

Comment: `<div class="foo" <!-- onclick="bar();" /-->`worked like a charm (Chrome), your edit `<div class="foo" <!-- onclick="bar();" --> >` did not and the `>` was still visible.

Comment: Did it? It didn't work in IE so I updated my answer to use `<%`

Comment: That is nonsense (unless, perhaps, you are writing ASP instead of HTML. I don't know ASP comment syntax). It depends on browsers mishandling HTML in order to work.

Comment: @Quentin Though I didn't test it on ASP/JSP for this exact problem, I'm quite sure that `<%-- --%>` are not sent to browser. They get filtered during compilation.

Comment: They'd only get filtered if they were processed by a suitable tool, the question uses plain HTML (so no filtering there) and the only server side tag is *php*, which doesn't use that syntax for comments.

Comment: Yep, I noticed that it was PHP after I posted the answer. `<div class="foo" <?php /* onclick="bar();" */ ?> > </div>` should work?

Comment: yeah, the only thing that worked for me on both Chrome and iOS was the "forbidden" syntax, as seen in my first comment on this subthread. Forbidden Syntax has some ring to it! Using the commented out PHP disabled my javascript object, I think you were on the right track though.

Comment: @RD Just to confirm, are you saying `<div class="foo" <!-- onclick="bar();" --></div>` works? Also, what do you mean by 'disabled my javascript object'?

Comment: `<div class="foo" <!-- onclick="bar();" /--></div>` was what worked. in the correct functionality, the onclick() function would enable a button that would hide the popup layer. When using the PHP, the onclick function did not respond, likely because it was commented out.

Comment: in that case why don't you just use `<div class="foo" onclick="bar();" ></div>` without `<!-- -->` in div tag? It will work too.

Comment: woohoo! it does. I had thought the previous coder had the commented out `onclick` function in there for a good reason

Answer (score 0):

Remove the comment. My guess is that the browser is interpreting the comment close as the end tag. Just put the entire div in a comment, with a different version below.

Answer (score 0):

Comments are forbidden inside tags, so your HTML is wrong.

If you want a comment, put it after the end of the tag:

```
<div class="foo"> <!-- onclick="bar();" --> </div>
```

Additionally, you should not have a `/` character at the end of the start tag for a div.

In HTML (before 5) it closes the start tag, so you add a `>` character to the data. Most browsers do not respect this (your problem is due to the comment though).

In HTML Compatible XHTML it is forbidden.

In XHTML it makes the div a self-closing tag, so the end tag has no matching start tag.

In HTML 5 it is, IIRC, forbidden.

Answer (score 0):

The comment (`<!-- -->`) is markup that the browser is supposed to ignore.

In this case, your markup is invalid because you are nesting a markup within markup in an invalid way. You will need to delete the "`onclick="bar();`" or move the entire comment out of the opening div tag.

Comment: It isn't actually a tag, although you are right in that comments are not allowed there.